# P2P torrents: downloaded data greater than torrent size?

Tags: privacy, p2p, bittorrent

How can downloaded data be greater than torrent size?  In this case I already downloaded all size (100%) but after few days - missing 0.01 % of data.

I try to found explanation on internet, some users talks about bad sectors in HDD, but this is happened to me few times; I checked my (external) HDD and it pass tests about errors (*GSmartControl*).

Is it possible that someone edits downloaded files, for example **mp4 file** - for reason to be able to install some monitoring tool on my PC? Or to detect my real IP (even I used VPN)?

[image: image from bittorrent]

Comment: removed unrelated banter.

Comment: I don't understand the confusion here: your client very clearly says there's only 99.9% of the overall data available, nobody that's part of the network has the remaining 0.5 MB, and obviously, a P2P network with very fine-granular part hashes has some overhead. Also, your "some users" aren't completely right, but not wrong, either: "bad sectors" isn't probable, but bit errors on large storage media are. Bad news: everything in this world only has a probability of going right, including reading bits from a SSD or HDD. These internally correct most errors – but some 10⁻¹³ of errors get through.

Comment: if you have a very large hard drive, it's very likely that when reading it, there's at least one damaged bit. That's just probability for you. Sometimes, that breaks something (like here), sometimes it doesn't. Has nothing to do with physical drive health (which is what something with SMART in its name checks – it literally asks the drive "do you feel OK?").

Answer (score 0):

Downloaded data measures all data you download, including overhead of the transmission, duplicates and broken packages.

#### What is overhead?

Overhead is everything that is required for BitTorrent to function, yet not directly part of the data you wish to use. To use letters as an example, think of the overhead as the ink wasted on writing the destination and the return address.

Another possibility is that you did not select to download all files. Since BitTorrent does not work on the basis of files, but on blocks, you will have some overhead if the file does not align perfectly with block size (which it usually does not).

A good example for this would be drinks. Imagine you want to drink 0.75 L Cola, but they only sell 0.5 L bottles. In order to get your 0.75 L Cola, you have to buy two 0.5 L bottles, leaving you with an overhead of 0.25 L.

#### What is a duplicate?

Sometimes clients will send you data for your packages that you already have. In that case, your client may still download it, only to realize that it already has that package.

#### What is a broken package?

When data is transmitted over a network, it *usually* ends up exactly the way it was sent. However, sometimes some data may flip due to interference from the physical world. Sometimes clients send wrong data on purpose. In either case, the data isn't what it should be and it will be thrown away.

---

In any of these cases, you download more than what will end up on your disk. None of these have anything to do with malicious activity. In fact, even if someone wanted to interfere with your connection, they would have to find a hash collision, meaning the data would have to hash to the exact same checksum (which is next to impossible for modern hash algorithms).